# What is this '+' prefix on a Flow type definition?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Why are "counter" and "type" prefixed with a plus in the following excerpt?

```
export type counterStateType = {
  +counter: number
};

type actionType = {
  +type: string
};
```

(this code is taken from the electron-react-boilerplate app that
I am trying to get my head around. I have googled and binged and all I've managed to establish is that types come from "Flow").

Comment: I don't even know how to google that. To be honest I have tried but nothing came up lol. Only that you can use this in variables to get the numeric representation, eg `var k = +x;`

Comment: @Phiter Don't know how you people use google lol , i just googled "flow types + sign" and the first link was the duplicate.

Comment: @supra28 I searched for "plus symbol property javascript". Didn't try searching for flow types.